# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found for basic Spring Boot program

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I receive the "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" even though the Tomcat server seems to have initialized and running in the localhost:8080.

The pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-consuming-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The Controller is

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  

@RestController  

public class HelloController {

     @RequestMapping("/")  
        public String hello(){  
            return "Hello!";  

     }
}
```

The Main Application code is

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication {




    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

The console logs :

```
2019-08-09 19:53:07.161  INFO 13948 --- [           main] com.example.demo.HelloWorldApplication   : Starting HelloWorldApplication on DESKTOP-BIMC3QL with PID 13948 (C:\Users\AdharshD\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE\HelloWorld\target\classes started by AdharshD in C:\Users\AdharshD\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE\HelloWorld)
2019-08-09 19:53:07.164  INFO 13948 --- [           main] com.example.demo.HelloWorldApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-09 19:53:07.791  INFO 13948 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-09 19:53:07.810  INFO 13948 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-09 19:53:07.810  INFO 13948 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-08-09 19:53:07.891  INFO 13948 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-09 19:53:07.891  INFO 13948 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 679 ms
2019-08-09 19:53:08.076  INFO 13948 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-09 19:53:08.079  INFO 13948 --- [           main] com.example.demo.HelloWorldApplication   : Started HelloWorldApplication in 1.211 seconds (JVM running for 1.855)
```

Comment: Are you making a request at `localhost:8080/` I can't see any 404 in logs

Comment: @Patel, since when 404 error start coming in server logs ??

Comment: What I mean is if the OP has called the endpoint there should be an 404 message

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `spring-boot-starter-web` artifact. Artifact contains tells spring boot to scan the package (in which main method is present) and all his subpackage for configuration, components and controller. Since this artifact is missing, spring doesn’t register your controller and throws 404-Not found.